# Give Community a short bio that partly explains why you're seeing one of its posts/edits

Tags: feature-request, community-user

So, as part of what the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user does, it owns edits that were suggested by anons (such as [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/33367/revisions)). Some people might not know this, so they wonder why it's happened. Rolling over Community's avatar for the expanded usercard gives this:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention Own community questi...

...which makes sense because that's what its profile says. But given that having a post/edit with Community's avatar is relatively rare, how about it be given a profile summary of something like:

> Hi, I'm not really a person. I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> You're seeing me here because this post or edit doesn't belong to a user.

This would save having to go elsewhere for an explanation. (It would also get rid of the kind of ugly condensing of the bulleted list.)

Comment: Your condensed summary is incorrect, though. That's not the only thing that the Community user does. Everything it *does* do is listed correctly in the profile, the hover preview just doesn't show bulleted lists. It doesn't make a lot of sense to optimize content for a preview, though. If anything, the `[feature-request]` should be to make bulleted lists display as a bulleted list in the preview window.

Comment: I'd be content with simply a "Learn more" link that directs you to some collection of meta posts about it.

Comment: If you click on it, you find out everything you need to know.  Why is it so critical that this information be displayed in the hover-over summary?