# Community user's profile is incomplete, fix?

Tags: feature-request, community-user

The Community user serves many purposes on Stack Exchange, some of which are surprising when first encountered.  Could [Community's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) be made to list its functions explicitly so that if a user, say, wonders how Community ended up voting to close a question as a duplicate, a search though old meta posts isn't needed to find the answer?

Comment: It already does exactly that...

Comment: I'm looking for an explicit list, not an implicit handwaving list.  E.g. "I do these things" instead of "I do things like".

Comment: @Servy There is no mention of duplicate-closing, nor a link to documentation on how it happens.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123198/give-community-a-short-bio-that-partly-explains-why-youre-seeing-one-of-its-pos?rq=1)

Comment: The profile should probably just point to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/262755).

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce although that doesn't mention OP dupe closure.

Comment: Ah, but that's easily rectified by the community here, while updating the Community User profile requires intervention by Stack Exchange employees.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest, instead, that the profile be simply updated to add a link to [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/262755).

That answer (especially since it's Community Wiki) can be easily updated and vetted by the members of the community. Changing the profile of Community ♦ requires the intervention of a Stack Exchange employee.

Comment: Employees are the people changing the code that changes Community's behavior, so changing the profile isn't much extra work, especially since new text can likely be paraphrased from a code commit message someone already wrote.  Normal SE users don't see those changes as they happen; we only notice them later.

Comment: if the profile was kept up to date by the people who changed the code, then we wouldn't be dealing with the current situation, where the profile is out of date. I think that is good evidence for the need to either remind someone to update it (as the question did) or use a little indirection to point from the profile to something more people can keep up to date, as this answer does.